# How does PDO know last inserted id in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, pdo, communication-protocol

**EDIT:** This question title originally was: *How does Doctrine know last inserted id in MySQL?* and was related to *Doctrine* ORM mapper. After some digging I found out that this question is not related to *Doctrine* but to *PDO_MySQL*, *MySQL C API* and finally - to MySQL client-server communication. I have decided to change the title, so maybe someone will find answer to his/hers question.

For those who are not using Doctrine: I was curious, why bellow:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES('cat')");
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

or similar:

```
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES('cat')");
echo $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

will lead to only one position (without separate `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`) in log:

```
1701 Query    INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES ('cat')
```

**Original question:**

I have 2 tables:

```
category(id,name)
product(id, name, categoryId)
```

I created new category object and product object. I assigned category object to product object. I didn't set any ids:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->name = 'asdf';

$category = new Category();
$category->name = 'cat';

$product->Category = $category;
```

After that I flushed the connection and check MySQL logs:

```
1684 Query  START TRANSACTION
1684 Query  INSERT INTO category (name) VALUES ('cat')
1684 Query  INSERT INTO product (name, categoryid) VALUES ('asdf', '312')
1684 Query  COMMIT
```

How did Doctrine know, that the newly created category id is 312? There is nothing else in logs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did some research and browse some source code, so my answer could be a little bit wrong and not precise.

First of all, this is not really related to *Doctrine*. *Doctrine* uses *PDO_MYSQL*. But internally *PDO_MYSQL* uses the same thing as `mysql_insert_id` function - native *MySQL C API* function - `mysql_insert_id`.

The reason why there is no seperate `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` lies in the fact, that after the statement is executed (in my example `INSERT`), server responds with data and some other things included in *OK Packet*), including `insert_id`. So when we fire `mysql_insert_id()` we are not connecting to the server, to receive `insert_id` - mysql library does not need to do that - it already has this value stored from last execution of query (at least I think so after analyzing the file `libmysql.c`)

*OK Packet* is described here: [MySQL Generic Response Packets - OK Packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/generic-response-packets.html#packet-OK_Packet)

Comment: That's why we can use it, with no fear of query race. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably by calling http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: But that would be reflected in the log, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Pekka An uneducated guess: Could the log be configured to *not* write `SELECT` s?

Comment: @jensgram could be  - or it could be configured to show the results of function calls (namely `LAST_INSERT_ID()`). I don't  know how the query logs work

Comment: I already did something similar to `INSERT INTO foo2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');` and I have in logs string `LAST_INSERT_ID()...`, not the value of id itself.

Comment: @prostynick Did you try a simple `SELECT`? Were you able to find this in the log, too?

Comment: @jensgram Yes, I have all selects statements in log, also `SELECT last_insert_id()` or `SELECT MAX(id) FROM category`

Answer (score 1):

`last_insert_id` works only for `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns. It will not work if you insert a value manually into the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

The doctrine will work because it is just like assigning a `NULL` to it (although you never specifically write that). This triggers the auto increment and provide a value for `last_insert_id()`.

I have included a jpg here so that you can see it. Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't explain how doctrine actually retrieves the value though. There is no query retrieving last_insert_id.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question.